# Closed form for the expectation of the exponent of a normally distributed variable

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, normal-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

Chernoff's inequality states that, for any random variable $y$,
$$
p(y\geq t) <= \exp(-\phi_y^*(t))\\
 \text{where } \phi_y^* = \sup\limits_{\lambda \geq 0} \lambda t-\log({\bf E}(\exp(\lambda y)))
$$

Now, in case of normal distribution with 0 mean and $\sigma^2$ variance, the book says  $\log({\bf E}(\exp(\lambda y))) = 
 {\lambda^2\sigma^2}/{2}$.

I did not get this part. How they derived  the expression for ${\bf E}(\exp(\lambda y))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and variance 1, i.e. with density $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$. Then
$$ \mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X}]
= \int_\mathbb{R} e^{\lambda x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx
= e^{\frac{\lambda^2}{2}} \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{\lambda^2}{2} +\lambda x -\frac{x^2}{2}} dx\\
= e^{\frac{\lambda^2}{2}} \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x -\lambda)^2} dx
= e^{\frac{\lambda^2}{2}} \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^2} dy 
= e^{\frac{\lambda^2}{2}}$$
Where I used the change of variables $y=x-\lambda$ and the fact that
$$\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^2} dy =1$$
Now in the case instead that $X$ has variance $\sigma^2$, recall that it can be written as $X=\sigma Z$ where $Z$ is a Gaussian with variance 1, therefore
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X}] = \mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda\sigma Z}] = e^{\frac{\lambda^2\sigma^2}{2}}$$
by the previous calculation.